# Removing Divs of form elements with profile2 fields

Tags: forms, users

I want to remove the extra divs that get added like in the following example (user-register-form):

```
<div class="field-type-text field-name-field-phone-number field-widget-text-textfield form-wrapper" id="edit-profile-parent-field-phone-number">
  <div id="profile-parent-field-phone-number-add-more-wrapper">
    <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-profile-parent-field-phone-number-und-0-value">

    <label for="edit-profile-parent-field-phone-number-und-0-value">phone number <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
    <input class="text-full form-text required" type="text" id="edit-profile-parent-field-phone-number-und-0-value" name="profile_parent[field_phone_number][und][0][value]" value="" size="60" maxlength="255" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I already did YOUR_THEME_form and YOUR_THEME_form_element in template.php to get rid of extra divs. But this only works for the standard fields of a form it seems.

I am using profile2 and profile2_regpath modules and it seems as if they add themselves extra divs for the fields that are specific to the profile fields. But I can't figure out how to overwrite this behavior.

Any help or hint appreciated.

And just in case it is already written somewhere: I used the search function and could only find the standard solution for normal fields. Nothing specific to profile2 module.

Oh and some details: I'm using Drupal 7. If anything else is needed, please tell me.

Thank you, best regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [theme_field](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/theme_field/7) override to adjust the field markup.

e.g, for body field on article content type:

1. Copy theme_field to `template.php`
2. Rename function to `THEMENAME_field__body__article($variables)`
3. Clear theme registry cache
4. Modify theme function markup to suit.

Note, the theme function naming convention required the "field_" prefix on field names, e.g THEMENAME_field__field_example__article()